# left join with subquery NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

team_members, usertable and pointstable

At first needed to get all users not in team_members table

I did this with

```
SELECT UserID
FROM usertable
WHERE UserID NOT 
IN (SELECT UserID FROM team_members)
AND Location =  'my loctaion'
```

this works fine

but now I need to get some info from points table based on the UserID from usertable

```
SELECT usertable.* , pointstable.UserID, SUM( pointstable.RemainderPoints ) 
AS points FROM   usertable LEFT JOIN pointstable ON usertable.UserID = pointstable.UserID
WHERE  usertable.UserID NOT IN (SELECT usertable.UserID FROM team_members)
GROUP BY usertable.UserID
```

This doesn't return anything

Any Ideas?

Comment: This doesn't look strange to you? `SELECT usertable.UserID FROM team_members`

Answer (score 1):

Note that your original query can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT UserID
  FROM usertable u
  LEFT
  JOIN team_members tm
    ON tm.userid = u.userid
 WHERE Location =  'my location'
   AND tm.userid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
select users.UserID,Pointstable.UserID,SUM(remainderpoints) from Users
left join  Pointstable
 on users.UserID=Pointstable.UserID
where users.userid not in (SELECT usertable.UserID FROM team_members)
  group by users.UserID, pointstable.UserID
```

If you need more columns from user table in the select part, add the same to the group by.

Answer (score 0):

took what you did and...just in case anyone else has any problems with this

```
 SELECT usertable.*,pointstable.UserID, SUM( pointstable.RemainderPoints ) AS points ,team_members.* 
FROM usertable LEFT JOIN pointstable ON usertable.UserID = pointstable.UserID
LEFT JOIN team_members ON pointstable.UserID = team_members.UserID 
WHERE usertable.Location =  'South Molton'
AND team_members.UserID IS NULL GROUP BY usertable.UserID
```

Comment: Not sure 'cause never tried, but I think you can edit your own answer and 'accept' it if you like ;-)